# How to obtain onComplete with Room Flowable<List<Item>>?

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

I have an Android app using Room to save my favorites.

Here is my DAO :

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM favorites ORDER BY lastConsultation DESC")
fun getAll() : Flowable<List<Favorite>>
```

I want to use Flowable to enable my MainActivity to be notified every time a favorite is added or removed.

On my MainActivity, I want to retrieve all my favorites and make a network request to check some information about my favorite.

In my UseCase, I have the following piece of code to make my call

```
favoritesRepository.getAll()
        .flatMap { Flowable.just(it) }
        .concatMapEager { Flowable.fromIterable(it) }
        .concatMapEager {
            itemRepository.getItem(it.id)
                .toFlowable()
        }
        .toList()
        .toFlowable()
```

The `itemRepository` returns a `Single` when `getItem` is called. I retrieve a `Flowable<List<Favorite>>` from my `favoritesRepository` and want to turn each Favorite in an Item after making a network request, my method returning a `Flowable<List<Item>>`

I thought that adding `.flatMap { Flowable.just(it) }` would create a new Flowable that would emit onComplete once the item has been emitted (since Room will not emit onComplete).

That piece of code is not working, the onComplete is never called so the `.toList()` is not called either.

Is there a way I could achieve those calls (with concurrency hence the concatMapEager) while keeping my Flowable implementation (I could use a Single to be rid of the problem but I would lose the "auto notification" on the MainActivity) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll make an assumption that `realtyRepository` returns a `Single`. Try this.

```
favoritesRepository
       .getAll()
       .switchMapSingle { Flowable
           .fromIterable(it)
           .concatMapEager { realtyRepository.getRealty(it.id).toFlowable() }
           .toList()
       }
```

This will get what I understand you want, yet you'll still get notified when DB changes. Also, `switchMapSingle` will make sure that whatever work you have ongoing, will get cancelled if any DB updates occurs in the meantime.

Comment: Your assumptions was right, the repository called in the concatMapEager returns a Single. It works perfectly with the switchMap, it was what I wanted to accomplish with `.flatMap { Flowable.just(it) }`but this does not create a new observable source.
Thank you very much for your help !